# Set Matlab function parameter as uint8

Tags: matlab

Is it possible in Matlab to say what the function expects? something like this:

```
function functionA( obj,  uint8(param) )
```

Here I am saying that the function expects one parameter of type uint8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complement Rody's answer, there are four ways that you can do this:

1. Use a conditional and raise an exception if the argument is not of the expected type. The problem with this method is that you have to write a lot of code.
2. Use an assertion. See Rody's answer or [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/assert.html). One can argue that this is not what assertions are supposed to be used for, but you can certainly use them this way.
3. Use the `validateattributes`function. See [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/validateattributes.html). This is a very good balance between simplicity and utility. It allows you to check for a number of properties in an argument (and generally, any variable at any part of code)
4. Use the `inputParser` class. See [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputparser-class.html). This is the most powerful method of parsing inputs, but may be overkill. Also, the cost of creating an `inputParser` object means that it may not be a good idea for functions that are called repeatedly. Nevertheless, it's very good for the public API.

Answer (score 6):

Not on the function signature. Typically, you do this via an assert block:

```
function (obj, param)

    assert(isa(param, 'uint8'),...
           [mfilename ':invalid_datatype'],...
           'Parameter ''param'' must be of class ''uint8''; received ''%s''.',...
           class(param));
```